# Element.outerHTML stops div being 100% wide

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying a learning exercise of my own devising. I wanted two divs, one 25% wide and floated right as a sidebar, the other 75% wide floated left as main body.

Above this I want a nav bar - 100% wide.

One of the options I wanted was to import nav html from an include file so I can change that file and use it dynamically.

I've pulled together some javascript to run onload to do this. It loads the external file into the outerHTML of the div id=navimport
After much pain - I've got it working BUT when the outerHTML is loaded the navbar div is not 100% wide and so the sidebar nav floats up beside it.

The navbar still has width=100% set but the imported content loads below the div, not inside the div.

I've tired textContent, innerhtml, outerHTMl and nothing keeps the navbar at width 100% and the new content inside the div

Code shown below.
Page

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang=en>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="./img/favicon.ico">


        <title>Study Site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/default.css">

    </head>

    <body>
    <nav>
    <div class="row" style="border:2px solid red;">
    <div id="navimport">Loading Nav Bar</div>   
    </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container">

        <div id="sidebar">
            Side Bar
        </div>

        <div id="mainbody">
            Main Body
        </div>

    </main> <!-- container -->

    </body>

    <script>
    window.onload = function(){
        file="http://localhost/learning/navbar.html";
        x = new XMLHttpRequest;
        elem = document.getElementById("navimport");

        //Set up the call back
         x.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
              if (this.status == 200) {elem.outerHTML =x.responseText;}    //{elem.innerHTML = x.responseText;  elem.Textcontent = x.responseText;}
              if (this.status == 404) {elem.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
              /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
              //elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
              //includeHTML();
            }
          } 

        x.open("GET", file, true);
        x.send();
    }   

    </script>
    </html>
```

CSS default.css

```
    .row{
        width:100%;
        }


    /* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
    /* No media query since this is the default */

       #sidebar{
            width:100%;
            float:left; 
            border:1px solid blue;
       }
       #mainbody{
            width:100%;
            border: 1px solid green;
            float:left;
       }


    /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 768px) { 
       #sidebar{
            width:24%;
            float:right;
       }
       #mainbody{
            width:74%;
            border: 1px solid blue;

       }
     }

    /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
       #sidebar{

       }
       #mainbody{
            border: 1px solid orange;
       }
     }

    /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) { 

     }
```

The imported file  is called navbar.html

```
    <style>
        .navul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }


    .navul li {
        float:left;
    }

    .navul li a {
        display: block;
        color: #000;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }



    /* Change the link color on hover */
    .navul li a:hover {
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
    <div style="width:100%;">
    <ul class="navul">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry code is not properly formatted as three blocks but the stupid post code wouldn't let me put it as three blocks of code - kept telling me the file names were code and refused to let me post. Another example of computers trying to be too clever and fouling things up

Comment: `* { margin: 0 }` the width excludes the margin, which is a few pixels by default, causing the size to be `100% + a few pixels`

Comment: Just a heads up for next time on the formatting: just remove the 4 spaces before the titles, otherwise it treats them as code

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using **CSS Floats** (or even their more sophisticated successor, **CSS Flexbox**), I would style the layout you are describing by using the three semantic HTML5 sectioning elements:

- `<nav>`
- `<main>`
- `<aside>`

and positioning each using **CSS Grid**.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 60px calc(100vh - 60px);
grid-template-columns: 75% 25%;
}

nav {
grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
background-color: rgb(127, 127, 255);
overflow: hidden;
}

main {
grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
background-color: rgb(191, 191, 255);
}

aside {
grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
background-color: rgb(63, 63, 255);
}
```

```html
<nav>Navigation Bar</nav>
<main>Main Content</main>
<aside>Sidebar</aside>
```

Now you can *include* the markup for the `<nav>`.